# Questions about System.IO.StreamWriter

Tags: c#, streamwriter, savefiledialog

I have no doubt that this questions are of very basic character but for me it's quite hard...
I want to select a filename/path with saveFileDialog.
Like this:

```
    private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Get file name.
    string name = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
```

Source: http://www.dotnetperls.com/savefiledialog

Then I want to declare StreamWriter with the Path from above (suppose this works like this)

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1_FileOk.FileName);
```

This had to be done in the saveFileDialog1_FileOk function. Then I want to write to that file from another function/event handler (SerialPort has received data). And the filename should be able to change to a new file while runtime so that the data from the eventhandler
is written to another file.

But from that other function I'm not able to access the StreamWriter and I don't know how to change the file.

Also I would like to know how I can make the Data in the file accessable during runtime. In my first tests it's always written to the file when I call

```
file.Close()
```

b
ut then I cannot open it again.

It would be a great help if anyone could suggest me the way to go...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "but then I cannot open it again"?  How are you trying to re-open the file, and what happens when you do?

Comment: Your questions isn't very clear.  Do you want to write to the same file or different files?

Comment: You don't need to use the `FileOk` event-handler. You can do it under `if( saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ) { // declare StreamWriter here }`.

Comment: I want to write to different files then. On the other side is a microcontrolelr and I want to take a measurement, save it for example in data1.txt then switch to data2.txt and take a new measurement over serialport.

Comment: "but then I cannot open it again" means just that if it's closed I cannot write to that stream any more like "file.Write("test")"

Comment: If you close the file it is closed and can't be read/written to - you need to open it again with `new StreamWriter(...)` or whatever was used to open it in first place. Side note: consider reading [HowTo on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzb96fk.aspx) it may help you with your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly; the approach you have selected seems to be violating the principle of single responsibility apart from causing you all those issues.

May be what you should consider doing is to create a class that manages the a **static instance** of stream and use it from open dialog and serial port events
Lets call the stream management class **StreamManager**. It would have an implementation similer to the following code

```
public class StreamManager
{
    private static StreamWriter file = null;

    public void NewFile(string filePath)
    {
        this.close();

        file = new StreamWriter(filePath);
    }

    public void WriteToFile(string yourData)
    {
        file.Write(yourData);
    }

    public void close()
    {
        if (file != null /* and if not already been closed*/)
        {
            file.Flush();
            file.Close();
        } 
    }
}
```

Now you may call from `new StreamManager().NewFile(fileName)` open dialog and `new StreamManager ().WriteToFile(…)`  from serial port.

Please note I have not tested the above code and provided only as a guide. You should add more state / error management to all methods

Cheers